# EF 6 code-based configuration and migrations error

Tags: entity-framework

Using code-based configuration with the DbConfigurationType(...) attribute leads to an error:

The type 'xxx.Migrations.xxx.Configuration' does not inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration'. Entity Framework code-based configuration classes must inherit from 'System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration'.

How is this done with migrations enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself. You have to write a new class inheriting from DbConfiguration and place that into the attribute for the context class. Migrations is using its own config class.